# TinyMCE: site jumps back to top on keyboard input on iOS

Tags: ios, css, iframe, mobile, tinymce

I have a really weird problem on iOS when using TinyMCE inside an iframe.
Lets say we have a form with multiple textareas, each including the TinyMCE editor. Now we want to insert something in the third textarea so we have to scroll down a bit. Once we make a keyboard input in the textarea the site automatically jumps back to the top of the page. Depending on how far we scrolled earlier the textarea could be pushed out of the viewport. Therefore you can't see what you've been typing which is obviously a huge UX red flag.

This only happens on iOS when using TinyMCE inside an iframe; Android works fine. By default TinyMCE also implements its editor inside an iframe. So basically we have an iframe inside an iframe which possibly could cause some problems on iOS.

Sadly removing the iframe is not an option. The textareas also have to stay, so using the inline option for TinyMCE is not possible (afaik).

The phenomenon can be tested with **[this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Firehawk/hnks210j/)**.

Code for the iframe is nothing more than this:

```
<head>  
  <script type="text/javascript">
    tinymce.init({
      selector: "textarea"
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <form method="post">
    <textarea></textarea>
    <textarea></textarea>
    <textarea></textarea>
    <textarea></textarea>
    <textarea></textarea>
    <textarea></textarea>
    <textarea></textarea>
  </form>
</body>
```

I greatly appreciate any answer and possible solution since I've run out of ideas. I doubt it has something to do with my Javascript or CSS (since there is none in this example) but I think/hope it can be fixed with CSS. I just don't know how :)

Comment: Were you able to get this issue resolved?  I am running across the same problem and was wondering if you were able to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have IOS to test it on my end, but you could try to see if this peace of code helps..

It only tries to get focus on control.. on init hook

```
tinymce.init({
    init_instance_callback: function(e) {
        tinymce.activeEditor.focus();
        // e.execCommand('mceAutoResize');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too, even worse because the whole tinyMCE page was running inside a WebView of a native app on iOS. The problem is, when typing or tapping inside the tinyMCE iFrame, it loses focus and jumps back to the top of the page. Here's how I got it fixed:

When initializing your tinyMCE instance, you should define a setup function. Inside, do this:

```
editor.on('postRender', function(event) {
  var target = event.target;
  if (!target || !target.contentWindow || !target.contentWindow.focus || typeof target.contentWindow.focus !== 'function') {
    return false;
  }

  var refocus = function() {
    target.contentWindow.focus();
  };

  target.contentDocument.addEventListener('keydown', refocus);
  target.contentDocument.addEventListener('touchstart', refocus);
  target.contentDocument.addEventListener('touchend', refocus);
});
```

What it does is doing a re-focus on the content frame on each key press and touch event. Make sure, to do this only on mobile (iOS) devices.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

It may be a problem if you are also using the bootstrap at the same time.
If you are using bootstrap and tinymce at the same time, meaning in the same form, then the bootstrap overtakes the focus. So, simply remove form-control from all the input elements of that form. Then, it will work.